# Complex Arrays/Hashes

Tags: perl

I've an input in the below form that need to be converted in the form(see $output) given below, I did look at existing Q&As but didn't find anything related, can someone please help me crack this out?

```
$input = { 
           a => b,
           c => d,
           e => { 
                  f => {
                         g => [
                                {
                                  ab => 1111,
                                  ef => 3333
                                  ....
                                  ....
                                 },
                                {
                                  fd => 2222,
                                  as => 5555
                                  ....
                                  ....
                                }
                                .
                                .
                                .
                               ] } } };

$output = { 
           a => b,
           c => d,
           e => { 
                  f => {
                         g => { 
                                 1111 => {
                                            ef => 3333 
                                            ....   
                                            ....
                                           }
                                 5555 => {   
                                            fd => 2222
                                            ....
                                            ....
                                         }
                              }}}};
```

Comment: So you just need to change the `g` element from an array of hashes to a hash of hashes, right? What is the criteria for deciding which element of the last hash becomes the key of the new hash? Please post the code you've tried so far -- we help you fix your code, we don't write code for you.

Comment: What's special about the keys for 'ab' and 'as'?

Comment: In one case, you used `ab` as the key. In the other, you used `as`. What's the determining factor as to which value should be used as the key in the new hash?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you've included irrelevant stuff in your questions.

The question is about converting the value of a var (`$input->{e}{f}{g}`) from

```
[
   {
      ab => 1111,
      ef => 3333,
      ...
   },
   {
      fd => 2222,
      as => 5555,
      ...
   },
   ...
]
```

to

```
{ 
   1111 => {
      ef => 3333,
      ...
   },
   5555 => {
      fd => 2222,
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

With the extraneous bits removed, the problem becomes quite simple. The code is going to look like:

```
my %keyed_recs;
for my $rec (@{ $input->{e}{f}{g} }) {
   my $key_field = ...;   # 'ab' or 'as'
   my $key = delete($rec->{$key_field});
   $keyed_recs{$key} = $rec;
}

$input->{e}{f}{g} = \%keyed_recs;
```

---

Especially if the name of key field is constant, `map` can be used for conciseness.

```
$input->{e}{f}{g} = {
   map { delete($_->{id}) => $_ }
      @{ $input->{e}{f}{g} }
};
```